# Android.mk adding LOCAL_CPPFLAGS doesn't work

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

My source file can not include some header, because of local flag is not defined.

---

**SSS.cpp:**

```
#include <jni.h>
//This code is not defined:
#ifdef WORD
#include "Word.h"
#endif
//...rest of code
```

---

**Android.mk:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := word
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -DWORD
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := SSS.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

And one more moment, project build was successful, but I can not run it because of lots of errors in source file (Eclipse c++ editor still can not see my header).

Comment: Why is `-std=c++11` on its own line?

Comment: do not focus on it, without this line problem stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not `-WORD` but `-DWORD` ?
`-D` defines a macro to be used by the preprocessor.

And what this

> -std=c++11

belongs to?

Comment: The same problem. -WORD -DWORD WORD DWORD LOCAL_CPPFLAGS LOCAL_CFLAGS and so on

Comment: Please provide recipe line you have for src files?

Comment: do not focus on this (-std=c++11) line, it is not a problem.